# Зависает игра на PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Вот часть кода, из за которой игра зависает:

```
import pygame

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def shop():
    shop=True
    while shop:
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

shop()
```

Как исправить?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: переменная shop не меняет значение, всегда True

Comment: Вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Comment: а что должно происходить в этом учатске кода ? видно только вечное обновление экрана, что похоже и происходит.всё как вы задумали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что зависание происходит из-за бесконечного цикла, пропиши либо условие выхода из цикла, либо принудительный выход из цикла - break. Возможно, как вариант, не хватает условие наподобие, пока не замечено нажатие определённой клавиши или кнопки в меню магазина.
Содержание самого цикла прокомментировать не могу, ибо с pygame работать не доводилось.